# GCP: When my preemptible VM instance gets preempted is it supposed to wipe out my file system?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using a GCP VM for training deep learning models. I wasn't able to find information around whether preempting means my instance is stopped or whether it's completely deleted including the filesystem. I can bear the former, but the latter would be a deal breaker.

Comment: If you are using persistent disks you will not have data loss. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible

Comment: Thanks! I missed that

Comment: Adding to my comment: provided that the instance shuts down correctly within the allotted time.

Comment: Thanks. If you'd like, you can put this in an answer and then I can accept it. Might be  helpful for others.